# How to write test cases for ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

In past, I've written `JUnit` test cases for `API, Services, functions.`

1st time I'm working on some command line utility that will be run using `Java ProcessBuilder`.I'm confused how I'll write test cases for that.

For example, I'm working on ghost script to break PDF in multiple tiff files.

So How can I write test cases for this case?

Comment: Interfaces and dependency injection are your friends here.

Comment: 1 valid scenario would be 10-page pdf must be break into 10 separate tiff file's how can you write a test case for this using interface or DI?

Comment: Indeed I can.  However, I will not, because that would imply that such a request is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Begin with a known PDF file.
2. Break it down to tiff files and make sure they are all correct.
3. Store all these files in a safe place, accessible to your unit test.
4. Your unit test does the following:

   1. Invoke the script using Java ProcessBuilder. Let it read the known good PDF file and generate tiff files in a temporary directory.
   2. Compare each generated tiff file with the known good ones.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what are you going to test. For unit tests you need simple abstraction level over the API that you are going to use: test your own logic and verify that API was called via mocks (e.g. Mockito).

In integration tests you test your code as a whole and then verify the outcome. In your case you could pass some known PDF and then check the existence and size of the TIFF files produced by your script.